# Issues using a custom attribute in Magento for retrieve several products

Tags: magento

I have a problem with my code. I created a custom attribute called product_type, as single value, and I was used that value for filtering the products...

```
$productType = $_GET['type'];
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter("product_type", array('eq' => $productType));
```

Later, I had change the attribute for allow multiple selections. I mean, before change in the attribute behavior one product have only one product_type, now one product can have multiple product_type.

I was sure that the code could be continue working but it's not.

Any help? Thank U!

Comment: How is it not working, specifically? Are you able to give a product values? What are you trying to do, that you can't, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Well, I have two products (product1 with product_type 1 and 2, and product2 with product_type 1). When I make my filtering by product_type 1, only product2 shows up.